# How to deal with different set of questions for verification in C?

Tags: c, function, if-statement

There are some problems in this code which I am unable to figure it out. No.1 is with **printf()** which is just allowing me to enter name but date of birth. No.2 is maybe the the problem with **if statement**. No. 3 is that the **else statement** just stops the process but didn't show me the message.

```
int list_view(char *name, char *dob, char *id, char *phone_num, char *address, char *account, char *fixing, char *amount){
    printf("To show you details, please enter the person name and id card number: \n");
    printf("Enter your Name: ");
    printf("Enter you Date of Birth: ");

    if(fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin) && fgets(dob, sizeof dob, stdin)){
        FILE * fr;
        int one_by_one;
        fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt", "r");

        for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
            printf("\nHere is your "); /* listing is transferred above just to show ones */
            while((one_by_one = fgetc(fr)) != EOF && one_by_one != '\n'){
                printf("%c",one_by_one); /*  display on screen*/
            }
        }  /* end of for loop */
        fclose(fr);
    }   /* end of if statement */

    else{
        printf("No access");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should prompt and get each piece of input in turn. ie

```
printf("Enter your Name: ");
fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin); /// with some checking
printf("Enter you Date of Birth: ");
fgets(dob, sizeof dob, stdin); // with some checking
```

second,

```
sizeof name
```

is useless, its the size of a pointer. If these input buffers are supplied by the caller then they have to pass in a buffer size arg too.

You seem hung up on your 'if'.

This is what you need I think. If they dont enter a value for either prompt then you want to say 'no access' and return

```
printf("Enter your Name: ");
if(!fgets(name, namesize, stdin))
{ 
   printf("no access");
   return;
}
printf("Enter you Date of Birth: ");
if(!fgets(dob, dobsize, stdin))
{ 
   printf("no access");
   return;
}
```

Comment: Then how to declare the if statement?